# Remove hidden input value if value not selected from Typeahead.js

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I'm using Typeahead.js for my suggestions, with id / value combo. On select, I'm setting the value of a hidden element to id.

The problem is, when the user first selects something from Typeahead's suggestions, and than fills some other value manually - the old id value from Typeahead remains in the hidden element.

Is there a way to remove the hidden id input value, if the user didn't select it from Typeahead suggestions?

EDIT: 
The function that adds the id value:

```
$('.lang').on("typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted", function(e,datum) {
    $(this).parent().parent().nextAll('.lang_id').val(datum.id);
});
```

The input:

```
<input type="hidden" class="lang_id" value="" name="lang_row[<?php echo $i; ?>][lang_id]" id="lang_row_[<?php echo $i; ?>]_lang_id"/>
```

Comment: Some example code would really help...

Answer (score 1):

You should listen for a change event on the typeahead input, and when that occurs, remove the id from the hidden input because you know the user has entered text manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of typeahead:selected and change event to track the changes and update the id of hidden input

```
$('.lang').on("typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted", function(e,datum) {
    $(this).parent().parent().nextAll('.lang_id').val(datum.id);
    // add selected text as data 
    $(this).parent().parent().nextAll('.lang_id').data('name',datum.name);
}).on("change", function(e,datum) {
    var selectedval=$(this).parent().parent().nextAll('.lang_id').data('name');
    if(selectedval!=$(this).val()){
        console.log('ID reset to blank');
       $(this).parent().parent().nextAll('.lang_id').val('');                   
    }
});
```